# Outlook Web App does not allow Calibri 11 as default font

Tags: microsoft-outlook, outlook-web-access

Normal Outlook for Windows uses Calibri 11 as default font. When I use Outlook Web Access, the default is Calibri 12 or can be changed in settings to Calibri 10, but not to Calibri 11. If I respond with Calibri 12 to my boss then my font is bigger than his and Calibri 10 is too small. How do I set default font in Outlook Web Access to Calibri 11? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

According to my research, I can successfully modify it via Settings>Mail>Compose and reply>Message format like below on the web mail.

[image]